# [TypeError: Network request failed]

Tags: react-native

I am working on social media where u can upload images video text it work perfectly fine when I upload text image and video but when I try to upload image or video individually it give this error network request failed!! why??
[enter image descript[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNfe6.png)ion here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P51fM.png)

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QALlX.png)

Comment: Show us some code and also show us the Error Log.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i update my question

Comment: don't add code as images

Comment: i added error log

Answer (score 0):

Try updating flipper version in android/gradle.properties

```
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.75.1
```

Make sure to sync the project and rebuild.

Edit: If you're using react-native-debugger, you would have to disable network inspect, otherwise the media files will not be able to upload.

Comment: what network inspect ? i simply running my app on android phone

Comment: If you're not running any debugger then you don't have anything else to do. Just change flipper version

Comment: my current version is FLIPPER_VERSION=0.54.0 ? which version

Comment: Update it to the aforementioned version

Comment: i change it to this FLIPPER_VERSION=0.75.1 but still getting same error